# Schedule weekly import of documents from external location

Tags: data-loader, scheduled-job, data-import

I want to schedule a weekly batch import of documents from an external drive into Salesforce.

Say, in the external drive there is a folder called  'CompetitorScore' and in that folder there are 50 files (pdf document), each for one of the AccountRecord in Salesforce. I want to get each of the Attachment and relate it to correct Account in salesforce.

Every Week the old files in the external drive will be deleted, and new ones inserted. I want to be able to do the same in Salesforce when the weekly import happens. Delete the old attachment from AccountRecord, and replace with new attachment.

I think this may not be possible with Dataloader or free version of Dataloader.io, would this be possible with free version of Jitterbit

If not what would be my options?

Thank You !.

Comment: i have found the most success for migrating files, regardless of their size, by coding my own java application for this using the REST API. but if you wish to do this on a schedule, have you considered mulesoft integrations with the remote server? I have used jitterbit, it worked but not consistently for this task. Issues i ran into were the files were all being written as the same file. the mappings were not being honored and with Jitterbit, you would have to be sure to recapture the contents of that drive every time.

Comment: While not free, Realfire Dataloader allows you to implement multi step dataloader with dmls support so you can delete all records in one step and import attachments in another. Attachments could be in local file system or google drive.